# Java и c# unity3d

Tags: java, c#, unity3d

Друзья, такой вопрос: допустим у меня есть простое приложение, написанное на java. Приложение состоит из нескольких переменных, нескольких layout-ов и нескольких кнопок для переходов по этим layout. И есть игра, написанная на c# на движке unity. В игре уже есть некое меню, 3d модели с анимация и и кое-какими скриптами для взаимодействия.
Вот я хотел узнать, можно ли соединить эти две программы, чтобы переходить с приложения на java в игру на c# и на сколько это глупая затея?

Comment: Под виндой, теоретический вроде можно. На ~3814%!

Comment: Переходить возможность имеется. Если я правильно понимаю, на Java что-то типо лаунчера, для запуска игры?

Comment: зависит от того, что означает `соединить эти две программы`. В порядке увеличения сложности:  Запускать одну программу из другой? Запустить 2 программы и заставить их общаться?  Соединить их так, чтобы это стало одной программой с одним юзер интерфейсом?

Comment: Ситуация заключается в следующем: сейчас у меня нет возможности работать с unity, поэтому я хочу сперва написать простое приложение со ссылками и при возможности добраться до unity, где у меня уже есть готовая игра и соединить эти две программы в одну.

Answer (score 0):

Чисто теоретически можно написать простую логику на Java, а потом сконвертировать еë в  С# *(ссылка прилагается)*

> https://www.javainuse.com/java2csharp

Однако навряд ли вы сможете сделать что-сложнее калькулятора *(то же API Unity сфокусировано на С#)*

Answer (score 0):

Для начала: зачем вам смешивать вашу игру на C# и какое-то сторонее приложение на Java? Просто напишите функционал вашего Java приложения на Unity и C#. Вы пройдёте мимо всех трудностей.

Если же вы всё таки решите сделать по своему, то стоит обьяснить, что значит:

> Соединить эти две программы

Если вы хотите просто запускать игру с помощью Java приложения, то используйте средства встроенные в Java для запуска файлов на ПК.

Если вам нужно, чтобы программы работали вместе и обменивались данными во время работы, то используйте сокеты. Библиотеки для работы с ними также поставляются вместе с стандартными пакетами C# и Java.

Руководство по сокетам для начинающих в Java: https://proglang.su/java/networking

Руководство по сокетам для начинающих в C#: https://metanit.com/sharp/net/3.1.php